# Ruby: Trouble with scope and class / instance methods

Tags: ruby, scope, instance-variables, class-variables

I'm having some trouble understanding scope in ruby.

Here is a link to a repo if you'd like to download/run what I'm talking about to see for yourself:

https://github.com/minervadreaming/killshit

I have several .rb files present - specifically, I'm having an issue calling a class method from an instance. Seems like I'm not properly following scope, but I'm not sure how or why.

Here is a snippet from room.rb:

```
module KillShit
    class Room
        attr_reader :player, :monster, :game

        def initialize(player, monster, game)
            @player = player
            @monster = monster
            @game = game
        end

        def action
            outline
            Player.describe(player)
            vs
            Monster.describe(monster)
            outline

            #rolling a d20 to see who takes a turn
            turn = rand(1..100)

            if turn <= 20
                monster_attack
            else
                puts "What would you like to do?"
                puts "1. Attack!"
                puts "2. Defend!"
                puts "3. Run away!"
                #Give the player magic if they're at least level 2
                if player.maglevel >= 1
                    puts "4. Cast spell"
                else
                end

                prompt; action = gets.chomp

                if action == "1"
                    attack(player, monster)
                elsif action == "2"
                    defend
                elsif action == "3"
                    flee
                elsif action == "4" && player.maglevel >= 1
                    magic
                else
                    action
                end
            end
        end

        def magic
            puts "What magic would you like to cast?"
            if player.maglevel == 1
                puts "1. Heal"
                puts "2. Fireball"
                puts "3. Tremor"
                prompt; magic = gets.chomp

                if magic == "1"
                    Spells.heal(player)
                elsif magic == "2"
                    Spells.fireball(player, monster)
                elsif magic == "3"
                    Spells.tremor(player, monster)
                else
                    magic
                end
            elsif player.maglevel == 2
                puts "1. Greater Heal"
                puts "2. Firestorm"
                puts "3. Earthquake"
                prompt; magic = gets.chomp

                if magic == "1"
                    Spells.greaterheal(player)
                elsif magic == "2"
                    Spells.firestorm(player, monster)
                elsif magic == "3"
                    Spells.earthquake(player, monster)
                else
                    magic
                end
            else
            end
        end
    end
end
```

As you can see, when the player chooses to cast a spell it calls out to a Spells class, which I have in spells.rb. Here is a snippet from that code:

```
require_relative 'room'
require_relative 'player'
require_relative 'monster'

module KillShit
    class Spells
        attr_accessor :player, :monster

    #Checking if user has enough MP to cast spell
        def self.mp_check(req, player)
            req_mp = req
            if player.mp < req_mp
                puts "#{player.name} doesn't have enough MP!"
                action
            else
            end
        end

        def self.heal(player)
            req_mp = 3
            Spells.mp_check(req_mp, player)

            player.mp -= req_mp
            amt = rand(3..10)
            player.hp += amt
            puts "#{player.name} has been healed by #{amt} HP!"
            Room.action
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is in the "Room.action" call at the end of the self.heal method (or just "action" as was my first attempt, as can be seen in the self.mp_check method). When it is hit, the following error is received:

```
spells.rb:27:in `heal': undefined method `action' for KillShit::Room:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I thought that it might've been because I needed to define "action" as a class method with "self." but that isn't doing it.  I also thought that it's because I'm trying to call "action" from the Class itself as opposed to the instance of the class with which I am working, and so I should call .action but I can't figure out how to do so.

Any ideas? What should I be reading up on to better understand the concept behind what's happening here?
Thanks!

Comment: Use the pry gem to help debug this. Make the program stop at before and after the lines of error.

Answer (score 2):

You Should call the method Room#action like:

```
KillShit::Room.action
```

Comment: I checked the file room.rb, in which you have declared a class method action and also in the instance methods of class Room, you are calling a method/variable with name "action". I guess this is creating some confusion.

Comment: If you are calling action from a instance method of a class then that should either be instance_method of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Just after a brief look - you did not defined class but *instance* method `action`.

*Class methods need to by referenced with keyword `self` or class name directly*, so you would need fix the definition this way:

```
module KillShit
  class Room
    …
    def self.action
        …
    end
    …
  end
end
```

Updated answer:

```
module KillShit
  class Room
    def self.action
      puts 'action in Room !'
    end
  end

  class Spells
    def self.heal(player)
      Room.action
    end
  end
end

KillShit::Spells.heal('Wallace')
# action in Room !
```

Comment: Yes - that is what I thought, too, but I get the same result upon renaming to self.action.  Do I need to call it in a different manner than "Room.action"?

Comment: You should not get the error then, no different way of call required. It looks you've messed up something different. Are you sure the module you are loading with `require_relative 'room'` is the fixed one ?

Comment: I've used your example and you can see it does work.